# Kotlin Unit Test Always passes when run from Android Studio UI

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to implement some Unit Tests with Kotlin in my application. The problem that occurs is that when I run the test from the UI, the test always passes, whatever I do. If I run the test from the terminal, everything goes as expected, the test fails when given the incorrect values. Does anyone knows why this happens? Is it a problem from Android Studio? Is there a way to solve it?
Even this test passes when run from the UI

```
@Test
fun testMe() {
    assertEquals(true, false)
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem here, but only for androidTest tests. Tests with "pure" JUnit run fine.